# script errors showing only with ie8 and iis7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, telerik

I have recently move a website from a server running win server 2003/iis6 to a new server running win server 2008/iis7.  When I browse to the new site in ie8 I get javascript errors:

Object doesn't support this property or method

And

Sys.ArgumentException does not derive from Sys.Component

These errors go away if I:

-Switch to compaibility mode
-Browse with ie7
-Browse with FF
-Browse to my old site (iis6 win server 2003) with any browser.

The page uses Telerik controls.  The master page also brings in the MS script manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be fixed in the latest version of the Telerik controls, since they've talked about such a problem with the IE8 beta in their forum, and promised a fix, which should have arrived sometime in April:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/form-decorator/form-decorator-amp-ie-8-beta.aspx

Comment: Well, for some reason my new site had the wrong version of the telerik DLL.  I moved the correct one in and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are browsing the old site with IE 8 NOT in compatibility mode? If yes, then you can try switching the new site to IIS 7's Classic App Pool, which should make it behave quite similar to IIS 6.

Comment: The site was already running the Classic .NET app pool but that would have been a good thing to try.  It turned out to be good an oldie but a goddie - DLL hell (see above)